# Vue.js not re-rendering when file state changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have the following code in Vue.js:

```
<div class="file has-name is-fullwidth is-light">
  <label class="file-label">
              <input
                class="file-input"
                type="file"
                ref="img_input"
                @change="onFileChange"
              />
              <span class="file-cta">
                <span class="file-icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="file-label">
                  Choose a file…
                </span>
              </span>
              <span class="file-name">
                {{ service.image ? service.image.name : "No File Chosen" }}
              </span>
            </label>
</div>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "ServiceForm",
    data() {
      return {
        service: {},
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onFileChange() {
        this.service.image = this.$refs.img_input.files[0];
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

However in the vue devtools I can see the image being uploaded to the state, however the tertiary isn't working and still returns no file chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a reactivity caveat, try to use `this.$set` :

```
this.$set(this.service,'image' , this.$refs.img_input.files[0]);
```

or you should initialize image property like :

```
data() {
  return {
    service: {image:null},
  };
},
```