# Vue not reactive to nested data() changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My Vue 2 fails to react when an entry is added to an object returned by data(). I can make it work other way but would like to know the underlying reason. See also [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gc1euqh/15/)

```js
var app = new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
    return {
        addedRows: {
        'section1': {}
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToList(chapter) {
        this.addedRows.section1[chapter] = 
                        this.addedRows.section1[chapter] || []
                      
      this.addedRows.section1[chapter].push({'T': 'XXX'})
      
      console.log(this.addedRows)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span @click="addToList('chapter1')">{{ addedRows }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) instead of  directly pushing it. Also in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) it specifies that arrays are not reactive.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450494/8172857

Comment: Thanks, from the same docs page I would also quote this section as relevant https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties